# animate a line under a title swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to animate a line under the word about. When you load into the controller a red line appears under about. I have been trying with UIView.animation and it hasnt worked and it dosent move at all. I want to to appear from left to right. If anyone can help me I will appreciate it very much. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need constraints for the red line:

I would start with leading constraint and width constraints which equals to 0.

Then you need to create an outlet for your width constraint.

And finally this is how you animate width

```
self.lineWidh.constant = 100
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: I did that and when I run the app, the line is already its final length. I put it in the view did load. Is that the wrong spot?

Comment: Got it. i just had to put it in the viewDidAppear. Thank you for the help